# What does "have a signing with someone" mean?

Tags: meaning

I stumbled upon it in the third episode of the fourth season of *Rick and Morty*. Here is the context:

> Rick: This dork. He has a convention now? Come on. What are we doing?
>
> Morty: Huh! Tuxedo scuba lessons? Ooh! **A signing with** Catherines Alpha
> through Omega Joneses! You know, this is great source material for
> this heist movie that I'm writing.

Comment: have a signing with someone means have a contract with someone: when both parties have their signs on the contract sheet, then it goes into effect.

Comment: Apparently, [*"Catherine's Alpha-through-Omega Jones" is a reference to actress Catherine Zeta-Jones, who starred in the heist film Ocean's Twelve.*](https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/One_Crew_Over_the_Crewcoo%27s_Morty) But even armed with that information, I have no idea why ***Zeta*** should be transposed into ***Alpha-through-Omega***. This is hardly the kind of source material I'd recommend for anyone wanting to learn English. In fact, imho it's stretching a point to even call this dialogue fragment "English".

Comment: @FumbleFingers [**Zeta**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta) is the sixth letter of the [Greek alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Sound_values). The first and last letters are **alpha** and **omega**.

Comment: Fumble. I think they are just having pun. A sort of joking.

Comment: @DM: I knew that. I just don't see why the substitution. They might as well have said she *starred in the heist film **Ocean's one-through-twenty**.* At least *that* could be seen as a "dig" at the idea of umpteen movie sequels (*Jaws Seven*, anybody? Not that there were ever any movies called *Ocean's One, Ocean's Two,...*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **signing** is an event where a notable person or group meets fans and signs [autographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autograph). These events are common at premiers, conventions, and other gatherings of fandoms.

An example would be a [book signing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_signing) where an author would meet their readers, sign copies of their book, and pose for photographs.

In the scene you describe, Morty is excited about the opportunity to meet **Catherine Alpha-Jones**, **Catherine Beta-Jones**, ..., and **Catherine Omega-Jones**, a reference to actress [Catherine Zeta-Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_Zeta-Jones) and a pun based on the [Greek alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Sound_values).